# (CORONA SDK) Sprite animation doesn't fall down

Tags: lua, coronasdk, physics, collision

I have written the code below to create an animation and a line that shifts from the right to the left. My problem is that if the line is no longer under the sprite, the sprite doesn't fall down.

```
local sheet1 = graphics.newImageSheet( "hero.png", { width=135, height=259, numFrames=14 } )
local hero = display.newSprite( sheet1, { name="hero", start=1, count=14, time=450 } )
hero.timeScale = 1.0
hero.x = _W/2-400
hero.y = _H/2+180
hero.alpha = 1
hero.myName = "hero"
hero:play()
physics.addBody( hero, "dynamic", { friction=0.0, bounce=0 } )
hero.isFixedRotation=true


local linea = display.newRect(_H/2,math.random(_H/2+290,_H/2+400),1250,10)
linea:setFillColor(255,0,0)
linea.alpha = 0.5
linea.myName = "linea"
physics.addBody(linea, "static", { friction = 0, bounce = 0 } )


local function muoviLinea()
    linea.x = linea.x - velocita
    linea2.x = linea2.x - velocita

    if(linea.x<-712)then
         linea.x = _W/2
         linea.y = math.random(_H/2+290,_H/2+400)
    end
end


Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", muoviLinea)
```

If, instead of a sprite, I use

```
local hero = display.newRect(100,100,10,10)
physics.addBody( hero, "dynamic", { friction=0.0, bounce=0 } )
```

Everything works as it should.

What am I doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you didnt call [physics.start()](http://docs.coronalabs.com/legacy/api/library/physics/start.html) all physics will not start unless you didn't explicitly start it